# Local Email folders dont come up on new OS 10.8. What can I do?

Tags: macos, email

I just upgraded my from 10.6.8 to 10.8.5. However my local folders are gone. I just tried to use time machine to access them however the time line before I made the upgrade is in red. How can I access those local email folders?

Comment: you mean the "on my mac" folders ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my MBA- 10.9.4 the "on my mac" mail folders are in the

```
~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes/
```

The Library folder is hidden since OS X Lion, so use the Finder's "Go To Folder" menu in the "Go" menu and enter that address.

Comment: Thx so much....